# WIX Bootstrapper with WPF Front End - How to approach UI

Tags: wpf, wix

I am attempting to build a WPF front end for a WIX bootstrapper.  I have the pieces in place and have a grasp of WIX, but my stumbling block is WPF. I want to create a Wizard-type interface with next/previous buttons for the installer. I don't want to invest a large amount of time in to learning WPF patterns, MVVM, etc, because I have little use for it beyond this. At the same time I don't want to create something that is hard to understand and maintain. I've have seen open source wizard controls that I am considering. Is there another "low tech" approach for this type of interface in WPF? I know there are things like Tab panels that I could use and just toggle visibility. Any suggestions or references for building an installer front end with WPF?

Comment: *Any suggestions or references for building an installer front end with WPF?*... sorry, but that's *not* [how this website works](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Take a look at the [Getting Started (WPF)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742119(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for that helpful note. WPF is a vast subject. I was hoping to get responses from people who have have built similar things (front ends for installers) and could at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, but this is *not* where developers go to learn a new language... that's *your* responsibility and there are already millions of detailed tutorials online. This is where you come if you have a *specific programming problem* with something that you are working on. On this website, there is an onus on the users (us) to show that we have made an attempt *before* asking a question... it doesn't even matter how poor our attempts are. So just try something and then return here when you can show your attempt and ask specifically where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below link, he has very kindly made and documented a simple managed bootstrapper using MVVM Light

http://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/